# How many threads to assign in selenium grid

Tags: java, webdriver, testng, selenium-rc

I am kind of confused while using Selenium Grid.
I have one hub and two nodes registered to it.
Node 1 - has 2 Chrome and 2 IE browsers maxInstance 2 each. MaxSession 4
Node 2 - has 2 Chrome and 2 IE browsers  maxInstance 2 each. MaxSession 4

In TestNG.xml I have mentioned 
parallel="tests" thread-count="4"

1. So how exactly does this works?
2. Will it send/execute all classes mentioned in one test tag to one node? 
   How many threads am I supposed to use here is it total number of browser instance so in my case it will be 8?
3. If I say parallel=classes, will it send/execute each class on each node?
4. What is the best way to improve performance? by parallel="methods"?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as I know, there is a recomendation to use only one IE per node.

1. Each time you request driver for test it will check if it available on grid and provide it to you.
2. Each test tag will take one instance of browser. To load all browser you could set thread-count="8".
3. It will execute each class on separate instance.
   2 and 3 also depends on how you create, shutdown and reuse drivers in your code (before test/class/method) e.g. you run parallel classes but create new driver in each method -> you will run out of browser in your grid, because they need to be quit before be reused.
4. It depends :) If you have resources and you metods could be run in parallel you may use "method" mode.